# ProgressBar show

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show `ProgressBar` in my application when I press a button.

The problem is that I don't want to use [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog) because I don't want a spinner inside a  dialog. I only want to show spinner therefore I just want to show [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html).

I want to do this programatically.

Comment: Are you trying to show Android's default progress bar instead of the spinner that the ProgressBar view shows by default?

Comment: no i want to show spinner but i dont want the spinner in a frame of dialog.just spinner..

Comment: Ok, so you want that spinner to be floating in the middle of the screen on it's own?

Comment: Check the code below and modify as per your requiremnets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your Layout.

```
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:visibility="invisible"></ProgressBar>
```

And in you javacode,use given below code in your activity and modify accordingly as per requirement

```
ProgressBar viewProgressBar;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    viewProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    // Your code follows here

        }

    });
}
```

And when you want to hide it , simply use

```
viewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Not sure, but does the `progressBar` run always in background(just hidden from the UI) after making it `invisible`?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the Spinner in your layout and give it the following attribute:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

or

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

When you click the button, change the visibility to [visible](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE) with [View.setVisibility()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29). When the action is done, just hide it again.

Comment: Not sure, but does the progressBar run always in background(just hidden from the UI) after making it invisible?

Answer (score 1):

For achieving this you need to create **two overlapping containers** for your activity. One container will contain your activitie's views and will be **visible** by default and the second container will be containing the spinner in the center with background transparent and it's visibility will be **gone** by default.
Now for creating an ovelapping effect like this you need to put both the containers inside the FrameLayout. 
Note: By container here i mean ViewGroups like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc.

```
<FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewsContainer"
        android:visibility="visible">
    ...
    ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinnerContainer" 
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00000000">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I hope this will help. Feel free to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) view instead of trying to use the ProgressDialog if that's all you want.

What you can do is declare your activity/fragment's layout with the ProgressBar already positioned, and then give it a visibility of gone (View.GONE). Then in your code, clicking your button will change the visibility to visible (View.VISIBLE).

You can also declare the ProgressBar programmatically, which should give you the same effect as using the XML layouts.